# SQLite3 & Py: Error Inserting hyphenated string

Tags: python, sqlite, insert-into

I am doing a simple script in which Python reads a bunch of tab-separated files, and line by line enters the first item in the line onto an sqlite3 table. The process works well, except for the actual data. The data that is being sent to me is in the format 123-4567890-1234567 (3-7-7). Instead of seeing the full string in the database, I get the arithmetical result of the three numbers in the string, i.e. -5802334.

I've tried all kinds of combinations with quotes, such as `Lines[0] = "'" + Lines[0] + "'"` (I get an error that the last item is an unrecognized token) or `Lines[0] = Lines[0].replace('-','_')` ("OperationalError: unrecognized token: "114_6555410_7421863")
.

Can you tell me what I'm doing incorrectly, and/or how to overcome this problem?

Here is my full code:

```
import sqlite3, os, fnmatch, csv, datetime

Homedir = os.path.expanduser('~')
DBFile =  Homedir + '\\Desktop\\AmazonProg\\AmazonOrders.sqlite'
Rawpathin = '\\\\idc-v-lapedi01\\amtu2\\Data\\production\\reports\\'
#TableName = 'OrderNums'
#IdColumn = 'Orderid'
#POColumn = 'PONum'
sTimestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
Lines = []

conn = sqlite3.connect(DBFile)
c = conn.cursor()

Amzfiles=fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(Rawpathin), 'order*.txt')
for Files in Amzfiles:
    with open(Rawpathin + Files, "r") as Source:
        Reader = csv.reader(Source, delimiter = '\t')
        for Lines in Reader:
            if Lines[0] == 'order-id':
                pass
            elif len(Lines[0])== 19:
                c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO OrderNums (Orderid, PONum, Timestamp) VALUES ({idf}, {v1}, {v2})".format(idf=Lines[0], v1=Lines[0][12:], v2 = sTimestamp))
            else:
                pass
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), which is why your query is blowing up.

Comment: what does one of these lines look like ? Irrelevant at this point but i think that the `commit()` has to be moved below the `execute()`. I could be wrong on this one though.

Comment: What Lines[0] is (show something)? how about str(Lines[0]) ?

Comment: You passing in the data without single quotes. So you resulting command text is `...VALUES (123-4567890-1234567, ..)` instead of `...VALUES ('123-4567890-1234567',..)`. But as @MarcB mentions, this is vulnerable to SQL injection and should changed.

Comment: Refer to the docs and specifically at the second argument of `execute`.

Comment: @Nicarus but the quoting is automatically done by the `csv.Reader()`, right? Especially for something with dashes in it.

Comment: Nope. Which is why your `123-4567890-1234567` is returning an arithmetic result.

Comment: Using `str.format` for this is asking for problems. The sqlite3 library provides a way for you to safely pass parameter values into the query.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis - The values would only be quoted if OP specifically set `quoting` to do so - or - if the value itself contained the same character used as the delimiter. Neither is true in this case.

Comment: Thank you all. Nicarus' change resolved it. I will look into SQL Injection Attacks. I'm new both to Python and to SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line is that you should not be using `str.format` for this as it is not secure and it is also, in your case, not producing the result you are expecting.

Fortunately, this problem was solved long ago. For you, just change your `c.execute` line to this:

```
c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO OrderNums (Orderid, PONum, Timestamp)
          VALUES (?,?,?)",(Lines[0],Lines[0][12:],sTimestamp))
```

Probably a good idea to review the docs - there are some very helpful examples included:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Thank you, Nicarus. This gave me the result I needed.